# Reading a text file and splitting into separate words in python3.8, using discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot using python 3.8 and discord.py in pycharm. The bot's function is to read a text file and write out each word as a separate message and send it into a discord server. Now I have the text file and it can print out the words but it can't do it separately.

Below is the relevant code:

```
f = open("test.py")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('r!help'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Help')
    elif message.content.startswith('r!start'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Starting Story...')
        await channel.send(f.readlines())
```

I read some other answers where they stated that `f.readlines()`would resolve the issue but that left it sending only one line of text. I tried

```
def script_message():
with open('words.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
           print(word)
```

and then trying to call the function with `await channel.send(script_message())` but that leaves me with errors where it's asking me to correct the syntax. So how can I send the contents of the text file as separate messages?

Comment: `for line in f: await channel.send(line)` would be the obvious attempt at this. Have you tried that yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
async def script_message(channel):
    with open("words.txt") as f:
        data = f.readlines()
    for i in data:
        for j in i.split(" "):
            await channel.send(j)
```

And in your `on_message` event

```py
elif message.content.startswith('r!start'):
    await message.channel.send('Starting Story...')
    await script_message(message.channel)
```